# How to retrieve data from service before updating the database (angular2)?

Tags: angular, service, get

here is my question.

I have a component where the users will be able to click a favorite button. That action will be stored in the database and it will update the value of "favorite" column. The point is that, for updating that value, I'm taking it from the database, I do it this way:
- I execute the get service in the component constructor to retrieve all the data of an specific post (name, description, user, favorites...).
- I give the value in the favorite column to a variable.
- When I click the favorite button I add one to that variable (variable + 1), and I send that to the web service.

The data is correctly updated in the database, but if I press the favorite button again the same value will be inserted in the database, because angular doesn't refresh the data I got from the service. The only way that it updates the data in my component is with page refresh but that isn't what I want...

Here is my code:

**service.ts**

```
updateFav (id: any, variable: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}updatePublicacion/${id}/`, variable, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'publicacion-individual',
  providers: [CynomysService],
  templateUrl: './publicacion-individual.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['publicacion-individual.component.css']
})
export class PublicacionindividualComponent implements OnInit {

    idRecibido: any;
    publicacionRecibida: Publicacion;
    favoritos: any;
    favToAdd: any;
    response: any;
    errorMessage: any;

    constructor (private cynomysService: CynomysService, private route:  ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router ){
        this.cynomysService.getPublicacionById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((p) => {this.publicacionRecibida = p});
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    addFavorite() {
        this.favoritos = this.publicacionRecibida[0].favoritos;
        this.idRecibido = this.publicacionRecibida[0].idPublicaciones;
        this.cynomysService.updateFav(this.idRecibido, (this.favoritos + 1)).subscribe(
            result => this.response = result,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }


}
```

I suppose that there is something that I need to do, but I don't really know what since I'm like new in Angular...

I tried to be as clear as I could but ask me if you didn't understand something from my explanation.

Comment: After updating the db, just call the get request to get all favorites?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `this.publicacionRecibida` is not updated after your update.

If you have control over the server side, then maybe its good to let it return upon your `update` service. If not, you will have to call `this.cynomysService.getPublicacionById` again, after your update:

```
this.cynomysService.updateFav(this.idRecibido, (this.favoritos + 1))
  .flatMap(
    result => {
      this.response = result;
      //call the get again to refresh your data;
      return this.cynomysService.getPublicacionById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    })
  //final processing
  .subscribe(
    result => {}, 
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    ()=>{});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I used the code inside my component but it is giving me this error:Argument of type '(result: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: updated. didn't read your code properly. You can use a `flatMap` instead to chain the observables.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Now it is giving me this error: Argument of type '(final: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.  I tried to get rid of the "final => {} part but when the method is executed it throws => this.cynomysService.updateFav(...).flatMap is not a function
    at PublicacionindividualComponent.webpackJsonp.98.PublicacionindividualComponent.addFavorite  I'm not sure if it throws that error just without the final => {} part anyway.

Comment: Just remove the `final` in the last function. it takes in no argument

Comment: It nearly works (I had to add import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'; in the service). It is updating the data in the database but since I store all the data retrieved with the get method inside a variable publicacionRecibida: Publicacion; I need to do the subscribe here //call the get again to refresh your data;
      return this.cynomysService.getPublicacionById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']); If I do the subscribe like in the constructor I get an error in the return. Sorry for all the bothers!